# Nouns expressing number

Tags: phrase-usage, numbers

> 1)I need **two million** rupees.
>
> 2)I need **two millions** of rupees.

Which of the above two sentences is correct. If both are correct, what is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 0):

When you're providing an exact amount of something, words like "million", "thousand" are kept in the singular:

> I need two **million** rupees.
>
> This city is two **thousand** years old.
>
> The blue whale weights four **hundred** pounds.

When you're not providing an exact amount, you use "millions (of)", "thousands (of)", etc:

> I'd need **millions of** rupees to buy this expensive house.
>
> This city is **thousands of** years old.
>
> The blue whale weighs **hundreds of** pounds.

Comment: So you mean my second sentence is wrong, if i just want to mention two million

Comment: Yes, your second sentence is incorrect.